# Is there a way to test the PsExec tool on a single machine?

Tags: vmware, psexec, vmware-workstation

I want to run a [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) demo, that simulates running a command on multiple machines in a network

Would I need a VMWare tool? I'm looking at Workstation 12 at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

No, just ensure your firewall rules are correct and sysinternal tools are installed on each machine, file and printer sharing are enabled and that your antivirus product does not block psexec.

VMTools gives you things like drag and drop, shared drives, improved graphics and code wise PowerCli. That can do things like Invoke-script which allows you to run commands on other machines this might be alternative you want to use.